# Anonymous function or equivalent within long complex select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

We are porting a SQL command to a new system, and it is a very long select statement with a complicated string parsing function in the middle.

Here's some pseudo code:

```sql
SELECT 
    812_ACT_RM.R1_ACT,
    812_ACT_RM.R1_FIRST,
    -- ... many more lines
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, 
         dbo.fn_parseformattedstring(1, W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF) AS KOX
    )
    -- ... much more
```

If you see right near the end, there is a function.  It is complex - parsing a multi-lined string and extracting text using charindex, etc.  For reasons that I'm not sure of, the function cannot be ported to the new system - and to be clear - this is a requirement from the new platform.  For the purposes of this question, the command is allowed, but external functions are not.

Is it possible to inline this function within the query somehow?

**Update**

Here is the function:

```sql
create function [dbo].fn_parseformattedstring(@format_id int,@str_in as varchar(max))
returns varchar(200)
as
begin
declare @str_out as varchar(max)
declare @idx integer
declare @idy integer

set @str_out = ''
If @format_id = 1 -- Date(s): {October 4, 5, 6 and December 8, 2010}  Time:
begin
        set @idx = CHARINDEX('Date(s):', @str_in)
        If @idx > 0 
        begin
           If len(@str_in) >  @idx + len('Date(s):')
           begin
              set @idx = @idx+ len('Date(s):')
              set @idy = CHARINDEX('Time',@str_in,@idx)  -- added @idx parameter
              If @idy > 0  
                set @str_out = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@str_in, @idx, @idy-@idx)))
            end
        end
                
        set @idx = CHARINDEX('Date:', @str_in)
        If @idx > 0 
        begin
           If len(@str_in) >  @idx + len('Date:')
           begin
              set @idx = @idx+ len('Date:')
              set @idy = CHARINDEX('Time',@str_in,@idx)
              If @idy > 0  
                set @str_out = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@str_in, @idx, @idy-@idx)))
            end
        end 
            
        set @idx = CHARINDEX('Dates:', @str_in)
        If @idx > 0 
        begin
           If len(@str_in) >  @idx + len('Dates:')
           begin
              set @idx = @idx+ len('Dates:')
              set @idy = CHARINDEX('Time',@str_in,@idx)
              If @idy > 0  
                set @str_out = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@str_in, @idx, @idy-@idx)))
            end
        end 
            
end

If @format_id = 2 -- Time: {8:30 AM - 3:30 PM}  Location:
begin

  set @idx = CHARINDEX('Time(s):',@str_in)
  If @idx > 0
  begin
    If len(@str_in) >  @idx + len('Time(s):')
    begin
       set @idx = @idx+len('Time(s):')
       set @idy = CHARINDEX('Location:',@str_in,@idx)
       If @idy > 0  
        set @str_out = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@str_in, @idx, @idy-@idx)))
     end
   end
   
  set @idx = CHARINDEX('Time:',@str_in)
  If @idx > 0 
  begin
    If len(@str_in) >  @idx + len('Time:')
    begin
       set @idx = @idx+len('Time:')
       set @idy = CHARINDEX('Location',@str_in,@idx)
       If @idy > 0  
        set @str_out = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@str_in, @idx, @idy-@idx)))
     end
   end
   
  set @idx = CHARINDEX('Times:',@str_in)
  If @idx > 0 
  begin
    If len(@str_in) >  @idx + len('Times:')
    begin
     set @idx = @idx+len('Times:')
     set @idy = CHARINDEX('Location',@str_in,@idx)
     If @idy > 0  
     set @str_out = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@str_in, @idx, @idy-@idx)))
     end
   end
   
   
end
   return  cast(@str_out as varchar(200))
```

I am sure this is not the best way to go about this.  It is old code and I'm not an sql developer.  I'm just trying to make the new system work as help was requested.

Comment: Is there an error message when you are trying to create it?

Comment: @Eric - no - I just don't know the right way to go about it.  There are many different variables.  Is it possible to define temporary variables within a select statement?

Comment: Why can't you re-create the function in the new environment?

Comment: If you can't re-create the function in the new environment, I don't see how you could inline it either. That would seem to suggest some platform-specific syntax (like regular expressions) is at play. Anything you can inline, you can abstract into a function. To answer your question about anonymous functions, no sql does not support lambda functions per se. You can simulate them to some extent using `CROSS APPLY` though.

Comment: Can the function be migrated into a CROSS APPLY?   As is, it is impossible to say without seeing the function.

Comment: What's the new environment? if you're within sql server, there shouldn't be any issue so, not sure what the trouble is. Perhaps better if you post what this function does, maybe there's a simplier way

Comment: Posted the function - It is basically parsing data out of a multiline text which is the body of an email.  @siggemannen, eric - It's not that there is a problem with a function or the environment, but for some reason we can't add functions to the database in the same way that we can add commands.

Comment: I suggest you don't inline that complicated logic.  Keep it hidden in the function.

Comment: Simple answer, No.

Comment: It may be more helpful to see sample function inputs and desired results

Answer (score 2):

You can do essentially what UDF inlining does: turn it into a series of `CROSS APPLY` conditionals.

You can remove the whole second half of the function, as your call has fixed the first parameter to `1`.

```sql
SELECT 
    812_ACT_RM.R1_ACT,
    812_ACT_RM.R1_FIRST,
    -- ... many more lines
JOIN (
    SELECT 
      W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, 
      formatted.KOX
    FROM SomeTable W_N9R
    OUTER APPLY (    -- outer apply usually forces immediate calculation, as opposed to cross apply which tends to defer
        SELECT TOP (1)
          v4.KOX
        FROM (VALUES
            ('Date(s):'),
            ('Date:'),
            ('Dates:')
        ) v1(dateText)
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
              dateIndex = NULLIF(CHARINDEX(v1.dateText, W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF), 0)
        ) v2
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT timeIndex = NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Time', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, v2.dateIndex + LEN(v1.dateIndex)), 0)
            WHERE v2.dateIndex > 0
              AND LEN(W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF) > v2.dateIndex + LEN(v1.dateText)
        ) v3
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT KOX = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, v2.dateIndex + LEN(v1.dateText), v3.timeIndex - v2.dateIndex - LEN(v1.dateText))))
        ) v4
        WHERE v4.KOX IS NOT NULL
    ) formatted;
```

Answer (score -1):

A close but not exact inline replacement without using outer apply (a fine solution):

```
SELECT 
    812_ACT_RM.R1_ACT,
    812_ACT_RM.R1_FIRST,
    -- ... many more lines
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, 
        RTRIM(
            LTRIM(
                IIF
                (
                    CHARINDEX('DATE', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF) <> 0 
                    AND CHARINDEX(':', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, CHARINDEX('DATE', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF)+1) <> 0 
                    AND CHARINDEX('TIME',W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF) > CHARINDEX(':', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, CHARINDEX('DATE', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF)+1)
                    AND CHARINDEX('TIME',W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF)-(CHARINDEX(':', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, CHARINDEX('DATE', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF)+1)+1) <> 0
                    ,
                    SUBSTRING(
                        W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF
                        ,
                        CHARINDEX(':', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, CHARINDEX('DATE', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF)+1)+1
                        ,
                        CHARINDEX('TIME',W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF)-(CHARINDEX(':', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF, CHARINDEX('DATE', W_N9R.W_N9_IDSF)+1)+1))    
                    , 

                    ''
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

This parses malformed strings like:

'Date*z*:  {October 4, 5, 6 and December 8, 2010}   Time: {8:30 AM - 3:30 PM}  Location:' even though it should not.

Comment: OP specifically said they are unable to create the function in the new environment.... not that it doesn't work as written.